# mysql - Duplicated value for primary key

Tags: mysql, constraints, primary-key

somehow I've managed to end up with a duplicated value in the primary key of a mysql table.

First of all, how was this possible? I can not think of a operation that would bypass the unique clause for primary keys values... To make it easier, I will show you the description of the table:

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| codigo_titulacion | varchar(25)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| nombre            | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| nota_corte        | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And now I will show you the duplicate value:

```
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| codigo_titulacion | nombre                                            |
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| 6001              | Grado en Administración y Dirección de Empresas   |
| 6001              | Grado en Administración y Dirección de Empresas   |
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'll bet there are characters you can't see in them, that are making it different.

Comment: What does `LENGTH(codigo_titulacion)` show for those two rows?

Comment: It shows 4 for both of them, also in the where clause I'm using titulaciones.codigo_titulacion = 6001 so that means both have that exact value, right?

Comment: why are you using varchar for your primary key instead of int? Change the type to int and when you try to do so the error message will tell you what exactly is in that record. It's extremely unlikely that they both contain 6001 int.

Comment: Okay @e4c5 I think I can see what happened thanks to you! I changed the values of my pk from varchar to ints to make it easier to work with them in my project. Probably something got messed up because of this change.